# View.setClipBounds() does not limit the View animation area?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, animation, viewanimator

I am currently trying to do a pseudo-circular reveal that will work on Android API levels below Lollipop. So, I have a floating action button (FAB) that I want (when pressed) to move vertically into a RelativeLayout (before clicked it sits outside of the RelativeLayout) and then scale by a certain factor so that it looks like a reveal.

I thought that using .setClipBounds() on the FAB would limit the scale animation in the area of the RelativeLayout but unfortunately the scale animation expands to take over the whole Activity area. This is the code in the click listener of the FAB:

```
 circleFab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int cardHeight = relativeCardBuild.getHeight();
                int cardWidth = relativeCardBuild.getWidth();

                Log.i("RELAT H", "" + cardHeight);
                Log.i("RELAT W", "" + cardWidth);

                circleFab
                        .animate()
                        .translationY(-(cardHeight / 2))
                        .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
                        .setDuration(200).start();
                tickFab.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(200).start();

                circleFab.setClipBounds(new Rect(relativeCardBuild.getLeft(),
                        relativeCardBuild.getTop(), relativeCardBuild
                                .getRight(), relativeCardBuild.getBottom()));

                Log.i("left ", relativeCardBuild.getLeft()+"");
                Log.i("top ", relativeCardBuild.getTop()+"");
                Log.i("right ", relativeCardBuild.getRight()+"");
                Log.i("bottom ", relativeCardBuild.getBottom()+"");

                circleFab.animate().setStartDelay(100).scaleX(20.0f)
                        .scaleY(20.0f).setDuration(500).start();

            }
        });
```

The logged values of the relativeCardBuild's left, top, right and bottom points are correct so I am indeed setting the clip bounds of the circleFab layout (it's a FrameLayout that contains an oval drawable and a bitmap drawable) correctly. Still, the scale animation takes up the whole activity screen.

Am I completely misunderstanding what .setClipBounds() does in this instance?

Comment: I have never used set `setClipBounds()`. However, it would not surprise me if `setClipBounds()` is effectively applied before any `scaleX()`/`scaleY()` calls.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this?

Comment: Nope! No idea how to solve it, I had to change plans!